# JSON Object to query string for an API request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, query-string

In Nodejs (v7.4), I am creating a query string from a JSON object so that I can change the names sent through the request. When I use the request_options var the query just times out. When I pass the request_options var code in directly it works.

Is there a mistake in this code?

```
var request = require('request');
var FirstName = "John";
var LastName = "Wick";
var request_options = {"url":"https://api.example.com",
           "method":"POST",
           "headers":"{Content-Type:application/json}",
           "body":{"firstname":FirstName, "lastname": LastName}
          };

var request_OptStr = objectToQueryString(request_options)
console.log(request_OptStr);
request(request_OptStr, function(err, response, body){
    if(!err && response.statusCode < 400){
    //do something......
    } else {
    if(response){
        console.log('ERROR');
        console.log(response.statusCode);
     }
    }
});
```

the objectToQueryString function can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/dgs700/4677933).  The output of request_OptStr is       `url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.example.com&method=POST&headers=%7BContent-Type%3Aapplication%2Fjson%7D&body%5Bfirstname%5D=John&body%5Blastname%5D=Wick`

Comment: I'm unclear why you think you need the options in the query string and not in the body of a POST request. Can you expand on that? (Either way you can use variables to set the values in the request, so...)

Comment: Just following the template to access the specific DB. The code works if I insert the options as string. The reason I can't set the vars in the request, it is expecting a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `objectToQueryString` function encodes query strings from an object and creates the url, so when you use `request` on `request_OptStr` all you have are `queries` and the http request fails because a its an invalid `URI`. What you want might be this:

```
var request = require('request');
var FirstName = "John";
var LastName = "Wick";

var request_options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": "{Content-Type:application/json}",
  "body": {
    "firstname": FirstName,
    "lastname": LastName
  }
};

var request_OptStr = objectToQueryString(request_options)

request("http://api.example.com/" + request_OptStr, function(err, response, body) {
  if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```